# Which among the following can form a subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $<a_n>$ be a sequence of real numbers define $b_n$ and $c_n$ as

$b_n$ = nth rational term in $<a_n>$, $c_n$ = nth irrational term in $<a_n>$

Then

1. $b_n$ and $c_n$ are both subsequence of $a_n$ .
2. Both $b_n$ and $c_n$ may fail to be subsequence of $a_n$
3. At least one of $b_n$ and $c_n$ is always a subsequence of $a_n$
4. None of the above

I think one of them has to be a subsequence of $a_n$ but I am not able to prove it , or generate any counterexamples to disprove it .

Can anyone solve this ???

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  The domain of a sequence is $\mathbb{N}$.  Notice that each term of $a_n$ is either in $b_n$ or $c_n$.  If neither $b_n$ or $c_n$ is a subsequence of $a_n$, show that $a_n$ must have a finite domain, contrary to definition.